# Symfony 2 - Dynamic form generation based on Entities association

Tags: php, forms, symfony, types, doctrine-orm

I have the following setup:

Entity **Result**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="result", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $answers;
```

Entity **Answer**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Result", inversedBy="answers", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="result_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $result;
```

Form **ResultType**:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{      
    $builder
        ->add('answers', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new AnswerType(),               
        ))
    ;
}
```

Form **AnswerType**: - this one I want to make dynamic, currently is deprecated:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('value', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => Answer::getChoices(),
        'expanded'  => true,
        'required'  => true,
    ))
    ;
}
```

What I want to do:

Result form has a **collection** of AnswerType. I want that each of this AnswerType to be dynamic depending on the current **Answer** is linked to.

For example if I have a function on `Answer::getRandomStatus()` - if it is *true* - the `value` field of AnswerType to be `text`, `choice` otherwise.

My guess was in `buildForm` method of `AnswerType`, but `$builder->getData() returns null`, and I can't make a distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should give you the answers you're looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

to have a better understanding of the above you could have a look over:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvents.php

Answer (score 0):

I´m also looking for this, but want an already implemented solution.
Take a look at the source code for the CollectionType, it makes extensive use of these events.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CollectionType.php
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php